# Sum all column values in laravel (values are dynamic and not stored in a database)

Tags: laravel

I have a table view setup as follows:

```
    @foreach ($payments as $payment)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $payment->formatted_date }}</td>
        <td>{!! $payment->formatted_description !!}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->tax }}</td>
        <td> ${!! number_format($file->where('PaymentType', ($payment->ca_name))->pluck('Last')->get(0), 2) !!}</td>
    </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Now of course this could return anymore from 0 to 100 rows or more. How could I total the tax column and calculated (${!! number_format($file->where('PaymentType', ($payment->ca_name))->pluck('Last')->get(0), 2) !!}) last column. I'm assuming both of these are done the same way? The tax column is retrieved from a mysql database, but the last column is retrieved from a constantly changing json file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections)

```
$data = collect($payments);
$total = $data->sum('tax');
echo $total;
```